# Swagger UI not exposing endpoints

Tags: asp.net-web-api, swagger, swashbuckle

We have 3 component in .Net Web Api project.

- **Framework**(ClassLib): Contains Controller Base, filters and
  dependency injection
- **DevHost**(WebAPI app): Act as a entry point of web API application
- **API**(ClassLib): Contains controllers, models,
  WebApiConfig and swagger config

Hence, SwaggerConfig class is resides in API library. Whenever I am trying to call **localhost/swagger/ui/index** , it's displaying swagger documentation page without endpoints.

Is there any way, so we can specify custom route object from where Swagger should expose endpoints?

Note: SwaggerConfig and rest part is configure correctly.

Comment: I think that the proper place for swashbuckle is on DevHost...

Comment: Can you share your WebApi startup code and your swagger config code ?